# How to I get access to the keys in JSON object from this API?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an app/website where you put the film title in and it brings up a link with all the details, but I am having problems actually accessing the data that I need.  I can get into the object but can't seem to get past that point and actually get into the stuff I want like titles, images etc.  The problem I think I'm having is that all the films that come back after the search are numbered and i find it hard to get past that part

eg

```
0:{adult: false, backdrop_path: '/v3ClsT59peXyGJ4XuDvIQAPwcZy.jpg', genre_ids: Array(2), id: 4133, original_language: 'en', …}
1:{adult: false, backdrop_path: null, genre_ids: Array(1), id: 1197042, original_language: 'ca', …}
2:{adult: false, backdrop_path: null, genre_ids: Array(1), id: 1114948, original_language: 'en', …}
3:{adult: false, backdrop_path: null, genre_ids: Array(0), id: 400489, original_language: 'en', …}
4:{adult: false, backdrop_path: null, genre_ids: Array(1), id: 468158, original_language: 'en', …}
5:{adult: false, backdrop_path: '/63HcRYJI4LKeo8sINlL71ZtlUFY.jpg', genre_ids: Array(1), id: 147, original_language: 'fr', …}
```

I've tried to use dot operators, brackets to try and get it but keep getting errors and don't know where to go from here to access the rest of the data from the JSON

```js
const getFilm = async(film) => {
  let titles = [];
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${film}&api_key=3a8e699848eee9f846905172e427dce7`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const keys = Object.keys(data.results)
      keys.forEach(film => {
        console.log(data.results[film])
      })
    })
}

getFilm('Avengers');
```

Comment: You code seems to work fine - is there something you wanted to do with the data in the `submit` handler? By the way, thanks for the working api key

Comment: Also you show the same thing over and over based on the number of keys

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.results` is an array, not an object with numbered keys. Therefore, you can directly iterate over it using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) without needing to call `Object.keys`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const searchForm = document.querySelector("#search-form");
  const searchText = document.querySelector("#search-text");
  const searchResults = document.querySelector("#results");

  searchForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const film = searchText.value;
    getFilm(film);
  });

  async function getFilm(film) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${film}&api_key=3a8e699848eee9f846905172e427dce7`,
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      displayResults(data.results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
    }
  }

  function displayResults(films) {
    let tableHTML =
      "<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>ID</th><th>Original Language</th></tr>";
    films.forEach((film) => {
      tableHTML += `<tr><td>${film.title}</td><td>${film.id}</td><td>${film.original_language}</td></tr>`;
    });
    tableHTML += "</table>";
    searchResults.innerHTML = tableHTML;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Movie Search</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="search-form">
        <input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Enter film title">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that.  I had tried iterating with forEach previously and it didn't work, so must have done something else wrong.  Thanks for clarifying that it was an array and possible to iterate with forEach tho, I've spent 2 days banging my head against a  brick wall and I've come on here and it was resolved in about 30 minutes!  Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Done and done :)